# Output object description in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, describes

Is there a way to query the description of a custom settings objects so I can use it in my visualforce page. Like OppCountryRegionMapping__c.Description?

[image: Custom Setting Definition]

Comment: The `Description` of your custom setting is metadata, so I'd think you'd need to use the metadata API to access that. Apex is gaining the ability to directly access metadata (starting with  Summer '17 - API v40.0), but I don't think `Custom Settings` are supported yet. I don't have the experience with the metadata API to provide a good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use API to get the description form object .
Here is the example:
"/services/data/v36.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomObject/objectID"

This will fetch all the details of object.

Comment: Where in my VF page do I include this?

Comment: you have to right the apex code for making a callout for doing this .
for more info please
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm